# Swift - Set UserDefault if not already set

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

My intention is to show my `InitialViewController` only once per user. 

The code inside of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is supposed to check on start whether the value of UserDefaults key `firstTime` is still true. 
If not, it shall not show `InitialViewController`. If it's true and the VC is being displayed, its button (see 2nd code below) shall set `firstTime` to false to prevent `InitialViewController` from being displayed next time the app is started.

I reckon I figured out the problem, namely: `defaults.set(true, forKey: "firstTime")` inside of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`: 
Everytime the app launches, it ignores the fact that the key might have been set to `false` in a previous start, since it sets it to true anyways. 
A possible solution might be to check, whether `firstTime` has already been set, if so it won't set `firstTime` again. *But I haven't been able to find a possible approach yet. That's where I need your help*.
 Removing it won't help either, since when the app is started for the first time, it needs this key to exist and to be `true` to show `InitialViewController` in the first place.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if let rvc = self.window?.rootViewController {

            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(true, forKey: "firstTime")

            if defaults.bool(forKey: "firstTime") == true  {
                let vc = rvc.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InitialViewController")
                self.window!.rootViewController = vc
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

```
@IBAction func buttonStart(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (nameInput.text != "" && startKmInput.text != "") {

            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(false, forKey: "firstTime")

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecond", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can just invert your logic and check whether the initial action happened or not, so you don't need to set a value at app launch. For instance:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if let rvc = self.window?.rootViewController {

            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

            if !defaults.bool(forKey: "buttonStartPressed")  {
                let vc = rvc.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InitialViewController")
                self.window!.rootViewController = vc
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Then:

```
@IBAction func buttonStart(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (nameInput.text != "" && startKmInput.text != "") {

            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(true, forKey: "buttonStartPressed")

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToSecond", sender: self)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted

```
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(true, forKey: "firstTime")

        if defaults.bool(forKey: "firstTime") == true  {
            let vc = rvc.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InitialViewController")
            self.window!.rootViewController = vc
        }
```

Will always first write true to the key "firstTime", then read that key and find it true.

Don't do that. Instead, invert your logic and use a "notFirstTime" flag:

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

```
    if let rvc = self.window?.rootViewController {

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let notFirstTime = defaults.bool(forKey: "notFirstTime") //will be false the first time
        defaults.set(true, forKey: "notFirstTime")

        if notFirstTime == false  {
            let vc = rvc.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InitialViewController")
            self.window!.rootViewController = vc
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works as well.